# How do I show $1$ is not a trivial odd perfect number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

This question related to my [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/211567/74330) question in MO ,some comments stated that the integer $1$ is trivial answer for [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/211567/74330) question ,but here i'm very confused when we say that the sum divisors of $1$ is $1$ it self then easly $1$ is odd perfect number and with who we are sum $1$ , is it with$ 0$ as $1=1+0$ but $0$ is not divisor of any integer number .

Here my question: Is there some who can show me why we can't judge that $1$ is a trivial odd perfect number ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: In number theory, a perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its $\mathbf{proper}$ positive divisors

Comment: then 1 hasn't a proper divisors

Comment: A positive integer $n$ is perfect iff $\sigma(n)=2n$.

Answer (score 1):

A perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its proper positive divisors.  That is, we add up all the divisors **not including the number itself**.  Therefore, the sum of all of $1$'s proper divisors is 0, and so it is not perfect.

Edit:  We are assuming here, by convention, that the empty sum $=0$

Comment: hence, the sum of its proper divisors is zero.

Comment: Is 0 a a proper divisor of 1 here it's a contradiction  ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafic The answer is assuming that an empty sum is equal to $0$. See Wikipedia ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum)).

Comment: No, $0$ is not a proper divisor. The set of proper divisors of $1$ is the _empty set,_ and we consider the sum of all numbers in the empty set to be $0$.

Comment: sorry i didn't get attention to the empty sum is 0 by convention

Comment: Even if you don't assume the empty sum is $0$, $1$ still can't equal the sum of its proper divisors, since the sum doesn't exist.

Comment: @user236182, pleas look my question in MO ,it has a relation with the integer 1

Answer (score 0):

Since the sum-of-divisors function $\sigma$ is *weakly multiplicative*, then we have $\sigma(1) = 1$.

If $1$ were a *classical $2$-perfect number*, then $\sigma(1)$ should be equal to $2\cdot1$ (which, of course, is not true).

(It turns out that $1$ is the *only odd multiperfect number* that is currently known.  $1$ is considered to be a $1$-perfect number.)